# How can I read the PDF file. First time whenever click link only download PDF but second time click the link only Read or view the PDF file

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have some link . First time whenever I click  those link respective PDF file are downloaded . But second time I'll click those it should not be download PDF file only directly view the PDF file or open the PDF through Node js .

Answer (score -1):

**index.ejs**

```
<html>

 <script>

                $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").click(function(){

            alert("ABC=====");
                $.post('/test',{
                    name: $(this).attr('href'),
                    age: $(this).attr('id'),
                    title: $(this).attr('name'),
               })

                });
                });


    </script>
<body>  

<% if(true){ %>
            <li>
                <b> Content Type : </b><a name=<%= item.Author.replace(" ","") %>.<%= item.type %> href="<%= item.link %>" id="G://nodeDownloads//<%= item.Author.replace(" ","") %>.<%= item.type %>" ><%= item.title %></a>
            </li>

</body>
</html>
```

**Main.js**

```
var fileo = fs.createWriteStream(req.body.age);
                    if(req.body.name.startsWith("http://"))
{
                        http.get(req.body.name, function(response) 
{
                          response.pipe(fileo);
                        });
                    }
else
{
                        https.get(req.body.name, function(response)
 {
                          response.pipe(fileo);
                        });
                    }
```

Comment: Is this the solution to your issue, or broken code you want to fix?

Comment: index.ejs call to main.js .whenever user click the link first time. One PDF are download and whenever user click same link on second time how to view the PDF file. not to be a download the PDF on second time click.

Comment: You probably want to use an edit to your question to add this info.